# Why the conjunction from Genesis 1:2 onwards?

Tags: hebrew, genesis

It seems that some choose to read into the text of Genesis 1 a title and also claim that day 1 begins in v3. Why would the text go through the trouble of connecting all the “verses” that follow to the first verse?

Why if verse one is the beginning, why would day 1 start later on an undisclosed day, arbitrarily labeled as day1?

The idea of a title likened to the toledoth interpretation also seems curious because it’s unlike the toledoth template. It bears no resemblances.

What is the purpose of the conjunctive being added after v1? Are they intended to point back to one reference point? Are they meaningless? Are they evidence of poor grammar? Or are they divinely inspired, intentional and significant; and how are they significant?

Comment: Researching publications explaining - **Why does the shva in Bereishit 1:2 express "vav" as an adverb (Now) in JPS 1917 translation?** To help determine : Why the shva causes the "vav" to be expressed in English as an adverb Now : "Ve" (וְ) instead of the conjunction And : "Va" (וַ), "Ve" (וְ), "U" (וּ) used to initiate each verse of Bereishit 1:3-31. * Interesting puzzle

Comment: Is this an article/document available online? Can you link to it @חִידָה? Also are they using the MT or the Hebrew text without the niqqud?

Comment: Max Lansberg's [JPS 1917] English translation of Bereishit 1:2 states **"Now-The-Earth"**, but Isaac Leeser's [1853 Pentateuch] English translation of Bereishit 1:2 states **"and-The-Earth"**. | Curious to find **why Max Lansberg (senior rabbi of the B'rith Kodesh Congregation, Rochester, New York) & Dr. Marcus Jastrow (JPS Editor-in-Chief) interpreted the "Ve" with shva as the adverb 'Now' instead of the Leeser "and".** < http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/jps1917.htm >

Comment: The sequence "*Then God said … were the [nth] day*" seems to define what happens on each day, for "n" from 1 through 6.
That there also happen to be sentences that begin with "Then God said" in the middle of days 3, 4, and 6 doesn't seem to be significant.

Comment: And hence it’s not significant that the first day doesn’t start with “and God said” but with “In Beginning God” does that suit you @RayButterworth. Why not? If we can make exceptions for other days let’s make another exception. In fact you’re skipping over a lot more conjunctions while only selectively choosing some and even they don’t follow a pattern. Likely because they aren’t a pattern

Comment: To me, the first verse simply says that, at the beginning of time, God created the universe; the second verse says that at some time later (denominations could argue anywhere from a few seconds to a few billion years) God started to build the Earth and its inhabitants, in the form we know. ¶ Notice that the only "create"s that happen in Genesis 1 is the original 1:1 creation, the creation of animal life, and the creation of a creature in God's image. Everything else is transforming, shaping, and finishing what is already there.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo, I don't understand. I'm not making exceptions. All 6 days begin and end the same way.  In particular, the first day *does* start with "then God said [let there be light]".

Comment: The first day starts at the beginning. If the beginning is not the first day, then the first day is not at the beginning, is it? “For in **six days** the Lord made **heavens and earth**, the sea, and all that in them is, and rested the seventh day: wherefore the Lord blessed the sabbath day, and hallowed it.”
‭‭Exodus‬ ‭20:11‬ ‭given the earth was only made in v1 and God made everything in six days, on which day was the earth made? Day 3? Show me where it says He made the earth on day 3 and I’ll show you He said He started in v1 on day 1.

Comment: "*Show me where it says He made the earth on day 3*": If by "made" you mean "created", I can't, because he didn't. ¶ Compare with: 1) Originally, Acme Construction built the house.  2) The building became rundown. Then Fred bought it, and looked it over. 3) Fred started the first day of cleanup and making repairs.

Comment: Given it was all done in six days according to God Himself in Exodus 20, there is no place for anything to be rundown. In fact it hasn’t even been built yet @RayButterworth. You have ZERO proof of a rundown earth. The text points to a fresh earth hours old.

Comment: Note that Exodus 20 says that God "made" everything in 6 days, not that he "created" them.  They are different verbs.  Creation and making are different things. Creation is what happened in the beginning; making is what happened during the 6 days.

Comment: I agree with Ray Butterworth - the pattern of "And God said, let ..." is significant and invariant: - (1) always at the beginning of each day, and (2) only once for days 1, 2, 4, 5, and twice for days 3 and 6.  Therefore, day #1 cannot begin in V1.

Comment: @Dottard can we agree on this? That the waters the Spirit was hovering over, God is not SAID to have made? The text never says that God spoke them into existence? They are outside your prescribed pattern “And God said... it was day n.”

Comment: @NihilSineDeo - absolutely correct - planet earth covered in water existed before day 1 as God had made it previously - before the start of creation week.  It was presumably created at a time such as recorded in Ps 33:6, 9 and Job 38:4-7.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo - see my answer to your other question - there are eight times that we have "and God said, let there ..." - 4 in the first three days and four in the second three days.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that some (including myself) suggest that Gen 1:1 is a title or summary of what follows is the for the following reasons:

- Every day of creation week begins with the statement, "And God said ...".  For consistency, so should day #1.
- If Gen 1:1 records a creative act prior to day #1 the "heaven and earth" were created **before** day #1 or **on** day one.  However, this conflicts with the actual record further down where "heaven" is created on day #2 (Gen 1:8); and earth is created on day #3 (Gen 1:10).
- The summary of Gen 1:1 neatly balances the chiastic structure where the another balancing summary is provided at the end in Gen 2:1.

I do NOT suggest that Gen 1:1 acts as a "toledoth" because that word is conspicuously absent.

All six days of creation week begin with a "waw" showing its undivided unity.

Comment: 1. The toledoth is the argument used to validate v1 as a title but v1 has no other toledoth-like equivalent. Hence not a title. 2. God called the firmament heavens, He made the firmament, it doesn’t say He made the heavens like in v1. He qualifies the firmament as being part of the heavens by renaming it.   3.The earth was not CREATED on day three, He said let dry land be seen, after the waters under the heavens/firmament were separated further. You won’t find the word to make or create anywhere in reference to earth except in v1. 4.What do you do with the earth in v2 if its only made on day3?

Comment: @NihilSineDeo - I see it quite differently.  However, I cannot see what point and structure you try to impose on the text.  You create great difficulties by suggesting what you do but that is up to you.  The text defines the earth as dry ground the heavens as the space between the waters above and the waters below.  End of story.

Comment: Another point if ויאמר אלהים “And God said” marks each day of Creation v26 has an additional ויאמר אלהים does that mean man was made on day seven? Or v29 same thing, is that day eight? Or maybe the days were counted as stated at the end of each day? Hence why, day six ends v31. Either it’s a rule or it’s not.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo - in fact there is a consistent pattern - day #3 and day #6 both have two events not one as per the other days.  I wish you would simply state what point you are trying to make with all this rather than rejecting what everyone else says.

Comment: *"heaven" is created on day #2 and earth is created on day #3* -- not necessarily. On day two, the clouds that enshrouded the earth were lifted away from the surface of the waters, while on day #3, the waters and the solid land were separated.  In neither case was there any creation, only transformation.  Similarly on the fourth day, the remaining mist was cleared enough that the stars etc. were now visible, again without any "creation from nothing". (Imagine the process as something like clearing up after a nuclear winter.)

Comment: When you show me clouds, mists, stars becoming visible @RayButterworth I’ll believe you, until then let’s stick to the text and stop inferring onto the text what makes sense to our modern cosmological thinking.

Comment: If the text defines the earth as dry ground, then why is there reference to dry ground in v2? Please explain? What do we call the earth under the oceans? When were these created? Are these dry ground too?

Comment: @NihilSineDeo - that is part of my argument for making earth created on day #3 and Gen 1:1, 2 an introduction and summary with Gen 2:1-3 a conclusion.

Comment: @Dottard Day-One did not begin with the statement, "And God said ...", because **bara'** was the work project of **'elohiym**--the many-faceted **Creator God**. That **creation project** yielded **"waters"** and **"the deep"--depth**. Later, on Day-One (formed light), and right on through Day-Six, the statement, "And God said", reveals that the **WORD of God** was singled out as being the **co-Maker** of everything that God **made--** from those Day-One waters. **THEREFORE** John 1: 3 affirms: All things were **made** by him (the WORD); and without him was not any thing made that was made**.

Comment: @Dottard For two more witnesses, as is required, the only other two acts of **creation** mentioned in Chapter-one of Genesis is in verses 21 and 27. Both of these acts of creation **(bara')** are specifically accomplished by the many-faceted Creator God, even though both the fowl of the air and man were **also** formed of the dust of the ground and made living souls. Creating was the work project of **'elohiym**.

Comment: @BillPorter - I agree but I am not sure what point you are trying to make.

Comment: @Dottard Only that since a limited amount of actual work was accomplished--the "forming" of light--on Day-One, that work was not accomplished by the process of "creating", but rather, "forming" from something already created--the waters that the Spirit fluttered upon to form that light. That Day-One action required the creation of the waters that same day, as Isaiah 45:7 declares: **"I form the light, and create darkness: I make peace, and create evil: I the LORD do all these things"**.  Both creating and forming were acts of the work of God on Day-One--without waters there is no verse-5 day.

Comment: @BillPorter - the verb "bara" (always an action by God)  is quite varied - it can be creation from nothing, forming, separating, etc.  Thus, the "bara" of V1 covers all the activities of all six days.

Comment: @Dottard I don't agree with the **"it can be, thus that's the way it is"** Hermeneutics approach. Your very answer, itself, contends that a separation is mandated by the statements, **"And God said"**. That statement was made on Day-One also. You must decide which direction you are going, then prove it by the Day-One **"light"**, just as you would use the sun, stars, and moon to prove your direction of travel.

Comment: @BillPorter - Again, I struggling to follow you logic.  See my other answer here >>  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/54323/in-genesis-19-was-the-earth-exposed-or-fabricated-%d7%95%d7%aa%d7%a8%d7%90%d7%94

Comment: @Dottard Why would you skip over the most basic and descriptive meaning of קָוָה, being  **to bind together(perhaps by twisting)--gather together**. This would suggest that God had an understanding of the matter--the waters--that He created on Day-One. I am not suggesting that it took man all these years of learning to instruct God that the entire cosmos is made from particulate matter, that when in a formless and void state would be considered as being in a gaseous-like state. I am saying that Hebrews 11:3 demands that God **knew all along** that He "made" the worlds from invisible things.

Comment: @BillPorter - perhaps but that had already happened by day 3 and so is irrelevant.

Comment: @Dottard You have not accounted for Day-One, and you are attempting to instruct Moses and his Source of inspiration how to count?